# Programa para leer números mayores y menores en C no funciona. ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Tags: c

Muy buenas, soy un principiante tratando de aprender a programar en C y ahora mismo estoy jugando con los bucles usando `While`, pero no he podido completar un programa que lea cualquier numero entre 0 y 99 y lea cual es el menor y el mayor.

Esto es lo que llevo:

```
{
    float numero;
    float mayor;
    float menor;
    printf("Dame numeros y te dire cual es mayor o menor\n");
    scanf("%f", &numero);
    mayor = numero;
    menor = numero;
    while((numero<100) && (numero>0))
    {
        if(numero<=menor)
        {
            numero = menor;
            printf(" El nuevo numero menor es %d!\n", menor);
        }
        else
        {
            if(numero>=mayor)
            {
                numero = mayor;
                printf(" El nuevo numero mayor es %d!\n", mayor);
            }
        }
        scanf("%f", &numero);       
    } 
    printf("El numero mayor es %f\n", mayor);
    printf("El numero menor es %f\n", menor);

}
```

Al correrrlo siempre dice que el numero mayor y menor es el primero que se introduce. Y los menores y mayores del bucle siempre dan 0. ¿Alguna idea de qué estoy haciendo mal? Mi profesor hizo un ejercicio similar con promedios y la estructura es casi la misma. Gracias de antemano, saludos.

Comment: La asignación debería Ser menor=numero y mayor=numero si lo que quieres Es guardar los valores

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un problema en la asignación del `mayor` y el `menor`. En lugar de asignarlos a esas variables, estás asignando esas variables a `numero` por lo que pierdes los valores.

```
{
    float numero;
    float mayor;
    float menor;
    printf("Dame numeros y te dire cual es mayor o menor\n");
    scanf("%f", &numero);
    mayor = numero;
    menor = numero;
    while((numero<100) && (numero>0))
    {
        if(numero<=menor)
        {
            menor = numero;
            printf(" El nuevo numero menor es %d!\n", menor);
        }
        else
        {
            if(numero>=mayor)
            {
                mayor = numero;
                printf(" El nuevo numero mayor es %d!\n", mayor);
            }
        }
        scanf("%f", &numero);       
    } 
    printf("El numero mayor es %f\n", mayor);
    printf("El numero menor es %f\n", menor);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay partes en tu pregunta que no entendi muy bien pero mirando el codigo puede que esto sea mas o menos lo que buscas:

```
int main(void) {

    float numero;
    float anterior_numero;

    float mayor;
    float menor;

    printf("Dame un numero: \n");
    scanf("%f", &anterior_numero);

    printf("Dame un numero y te dire si es mayor o menor\n");
    scanf("%f", &numero);

    mayor = anterior_numero;
    menor = anterior_numero;

    while((numero<100) && (numero>0))
    {
        if(numero<=menor)
        {
            menor = numero;
            printf(" El nuevo numero menor es %f!\n", menor);
        }
        else if(numero>=mayor)
        {
            mayor = numero;
            printf(" El nuevo numero mayor es %f!\n", mayor);

        }

        scanf("%f", &numero);       
    } 
    printf("El numero mayor es %f\n", mayor);
    printf("El numero menor es %f\n", menor);


return 0;
}
```

Nota: No lo he podido probar puede tomarlo como pseudocode.

Lo que comentas sobre 0, tambien seria en parte por el uso del formato `%d`:

```
printf(" El nuevo numero menor es %d!\n", menor);
```

si usted introduce un numero sin parte decimal digamos 5 y aplica el formato `%d` se le mostrara como 0.

Si en el codigo anterior usted pone `%d`, puede notar la diferencia, puede usar en su lugar `%f` para que muestre los decimales (es posible ajustar el numero de decimales que quiere que le sean mostrados) o puede hacer uso de `%g`.

```
printf(" El nuevo numero menor es %f!\n", menor);
printf(" El nuevo numero menor es %g!\n", menor);
```

para mas info sobre formato puede mirar esto http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 0):

- Si quieres guardar el número mayor y el menor a medida que haya nuevos valores mayores y menores, has de asignarlo a dichas variables.

**En una asignación, debes tener presente mientras programas, que el valor que se encuentra a la derecha del igual se asignará / establecerá en la variable que está a la izquiera del igual.**

*Entonces : para guardar el valor menor has de asignar **numero** a **menor**, y para guardar el valor mayor, has de asignar **numero** a **mayor**.*

- Si *número* es igual a *menor*, no necesitas asignar el valor de *numero* a *menor* porque ya contiene justo ese valor; A parte de que, en tal caso, no lo procesará para comprobar si (el valor de número) es mayor que *mayor* quedando dicha variable ajena a esta posibilidad; El siguiente condicional tampoco requiere pasar a la asignacion en caso de que el valor de la variable *numero* sea igual al de *mayor* por el mismo motivo : es innecesario.
- El segundo condicional puede depurarse de los dos pasos que aparecen, *else* y dentro *if*, a un solo condicional *else if*.
- Los paréntesis que contienen *numero < 100* y los que contienen *numero > 0* son innecesarios. Cuantas menos partes innecesarias haya en el código más rápido se puede ejecutar y, más claro y confiable puede ser su desarrollo al programarlo.

... En base a esto, el código quedaría así :

```
   {
    float numero;
    float mayor;
    float menor;
    printf("Dame numeros y te dire cual es mayor o menor\n");
    scanf("%f", &numero);
    mayor = numero;
    menor = numero;
    while( numero < 100 && numero > 0 )
    {
        if( numero < menor )
            {
            menor = numero;
            printf(" El nuevo numero menor es %f!\n", menor);
            }
        else if( numero > mayor )
            {
                mayor = numero;
                printf(" El nuevo numero mayor es %f!\n", mayor);
            }
        }
        scanf("%f", &numero);       
    } 
    printf("El numero mayor es %f\n", mayor);
    printf("El numero menor es %f\n", menor);
   }
```